# mysql join for two columns of one table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

Hello I have a table `tbl_relations` which looks like

```
 -----------------------------------
 | id  |  source_id  |  target_id  |
 -----------------------------------
 | 2   |   2         |   4         |
 -----------------------------------
 | 3   |   5         |   7         | 
 -----------------------------------
 | 4   |   7         |   4         |
 -----------------------------------
```

And other table `tbl_looksup` which looks like

```
------------------------------
| id   |  language  |  value  |
------------------------------
| 1    |  1         |   abc   |
------------------------------
| 1    |  2         |   abc   |
------------------------------
| 2    |  1         |   abc   |
-------------------------------
| 2    |  2         |   abc   |
-------------------------------
| 5    |  1         |   abc   |
-------------------------------
| 5    |  2         |   abc   |
-------------------------------
| 7    |  1         |   abc   |
-------------------------------
| 7    |  1         |   abc   |
-------------------------------
```

`tbl_relations` is mapped to `tbl_looksup` in such a way that `tbl_relations.source_id` and `tbl_relations.target_id` is the `id of tbl_looksup`

**My Problem**
I need to find out those records in `tbl_relations` whoes `source_id` or `target_id` is not present in `tbl_looksup`. It means there is no `id` exists in `tbl_looksup`. In more details the first record of tbl_relations has `target_id = 4` which doesn't exist in `tbl_looksup`. This is faulty record. I need to find out these records.

**What I have done so far**

```
 SELECT 
  tbl_relations.source_id,
  tbl_relations.target_id,
  tbl_relations.id,
  tbl_looksup.`id` AS tblid 
FROM
  tbl_relations
  LEFT JOIN tbl_looksup 
   ON tbl_relations.`source_id` != tbl_looksup.`id` 
   OR tbl_relations.`target_id` != tbl_looksup.`id` 
GROUP BY tbl_relations.id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get your desired result, you need to join `tbl_looksup` twice since there are two columns which depends on that table.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT a.*
FROM    tbl_relations a
        LEFT JOIN tbl_looksup  b
            ON a.source_id  = b.id
        LEFT JOIN tbl_looksup  c
            ON a.target_id = c.id
WHERE   b.id IS NULL OR 
        c.id IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a2c2/2)

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

OUTPUT

```
╔════╦═══════════╦═══════════╗
║ ID ║ SOURCE_ID ║ TARGET_ID ║
╠════╬═══════════╬═══════════╣
║  2 ║         2 ║         4 ║
║  4 ║         7 ║         4 ║
╚════╩═══════════╩═══════════╝
```

Comment: +1 Looking at your speed you should be banned for first five minutes to answer any question. :D

Comment: @hims056 No! `O_o` Please don't `:D` hehe

Comment: @JW. It is outstanding. Thanks dude

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  tbl_relations.source_id,
  tbl_relations.target_id,
  tbl_relations.id 
FROM
  tbl_relations 
   WHERE tbl_relations.source_id not in (select id from tbl_looksup)
      OR tbl_relations.target_id not in (select id from tbl_looksup)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

> WHERE tbl_relations.`target_id` IS NULL

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tbl_relations.id FROM tbl_relations 
  LEFT JOIN tbl_looksup 
    ON tbl_looksup.id = tbl_relations.source_id OR tbl_looksup.id = tbl_relations.target_id 
  WHERE tbl_looksup.id IS NULL
```